# My question is about returning a value from promise block in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

I am unable to figure out how to send or i.e. return a value outside from a promise.Consider me a noob as i was working with selenium-java for the past few years so JS is something new for me and it takes my life out to get a value out from promise, so i can use it in other functions.

I understand the fact that expect() allows us to directly verify results and we can write the required block of code inside a promise as well, but there are situations in which returning a value will help in re-usability at least that is what is feel...

```
util.readExcel = function(rowCount,columnCount)
{   
        wb.xlsx.readFile('./test.xlsx').then(function()
        {       
            var sh = wb.getWorksheet('Login'); 
            cellValue = sh.getRow(rowCount).getCell(columnCount).value;
            console.log("The cell value inside is " +cellValue);   
            return cellValue
        })
}
```

In the above mentioned code can someone please explain how to return the cellvalue outside the promise to be used in other functions like in JAVA :) . I am sure this has been answered in stack earlier as well but getting a reply to my situation might help me understand the concept much better .

If possible please explain with simple beginner examples than the ninja skilled ones that confused me even more in my previous searches. :)

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Hopefully someone can provide you the explanation you need in an answer but you should get the functionality you require by adding a `return` before `wb.xlsx.readFile('./test.xlsx').then(function()`. So it would look like `return wb.xlsx.readFile('./test.xlsx').then(function()`

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion but it is returning a promise object instead of the actual value . So now don't tell me i have to open one more promise to use that value :(

Comment: Thanks @DublinDev it worked but as i thought looks like i always have to open one more promise to use a value from previous promise...